# How to loop a switch statement until desired number is found?

Tags: c++, loops, switch-statement

```
cout<<"========================================="<<endl<<endl;
 cout<<"The amount you need to pay is RM "<<total<<endl;
 cout<<"=========================================="<<endl<<endl;
 cout<<"You can pay using ($0.10 [1] $0.20 [2] $0.50 [3] $1 [4] $5 [5] $10 [6] $20 [7] $50 [8] )"<<endl;



 cin>>choice2;


 switch(choice2){
case 1:
    total = total - 0.10;
    break;

case 2:
    total = total - 0.20;
    break;

case 3:
    total = total - 0.50;
    break;

case 4:
    total = total - 1;
    break;

case 5:
    total = total - 5;
    break;

case 6:
    total = total - 10;
    break;

case 7:
    total = total - 20;
    break;

case 8:
    total = total - 50;
    break;

default:
    cout<<"inavalid!"<<endl;

 }

if(total > 0){

    cout<<"you still need to pay "<<total<<endl;
    cin>>choice2;
}
```

Extra information: My total is $5

I am trying to let it loop until the total amount is paid, say I choose case 4 which is $1. It's suppose to let me insert the remaining amount I am supposed to pay, which is $4, but the program ends after I insert another switch case option.

This part, isn't it supposed to be looping until my total is 0?

```
if(total > 0){

    cout<<"you still need to pay "<<total<<endl;
    cin>>choice2;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help, I am also happy to learn any shorter way of writing this program if there is any, also is there anyway I can implement array into this program?

Answer (score 1):

No, neither the `switch` nor the `if` will cause your program to loop.

You're probably looking for something along the lines of

```
while(total > 0)
{
    cin>>choice2;

   switch(choice2){
    // left out for clarity
   }


    if(total > 0){
        cout<<"you still need to pay "<<total<<endl;
        //Instead of getting the input in 2 different locations, just get it again at the start of the next loop.
    }
}
```